# How can I pass JAVA_OPTS to tomcat in a docker container?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, tomcat, dockerfile

I want to run my spring-boot application with a certain profile. Therefore, I need to pass the `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` argument to the JVM.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.10-jre8

EXPOSE 8080
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
COPY myapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war
```

The application starts but the JVM option with the profile name does not seem to be set.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just simply add this in your `Dockerfile` :-

```
ENV spring.profiles.active=dev
```

and other option is below, by adding one ENTRYPOINT:-

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=container","-jar","/app.jar"]
```